# How to get the size of a UITableView's content view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I would like to get the size of a UITableView's content view when the table is populated. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Why doesn't `CGSize tableViewContentSize = tableView.contentSize` work?

Comment: reason is [tableView layoutIfNeeded];// Allows you to perform layout before the drawing cycle happens. -layoutIfNeeded forces layout early.so it will correctly return the size.like dreaming before doing.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
// Allows you to perform layout before the drawing cycle happens. 
//-layoutIfNeeded forces layout early. So it will correctly return the size. 
// Like dreaming before doing.

[tableView layoutIfNeeded];


CGSize tableViewSize=tableView.contentSize;
```

Comment: + 1 It is that simple since the table view pre calculates the height based on rowHeight or calls the delegates heightForRow for each row before ever displaying them.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the table is dynamically sized by its contents.

Comment: Working fine to me!!

Comment: @fatuhoku it works, u need to add this line in CellForRow after the last cell of TableView

Comment: I had a slightly different case, but the key with that was to set estimatedRowHeight = 0
_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;

Answer (score 5):

Here's a utility method that does it the hard way.  The negligible advantage is there's no need to call `[tableView layoutIfNeeded]`.

```
#define CGSizesMaxWidth(sz1, sz2)             MAX((sz1).width, (sz2).width)
#define CGSizesAddHeights(sz1, sz2)           (sz1).height + (sz2).height

+ (CGSize)sizeForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    CGSize tableViewSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    NSInteger numberOfSections = [tableView numberOfSections];
    for (NSInteger section = 0; section < numberOfSections; section++) {
        // Factor in the size of the section header
        CGRect rect = [tableView rectForHeaderInSection:section];
        tableViewSize = CGSizeMake(CGSizesMaxWidth(tableViewSize, rect.size), CGSizesAddHeights(tableViewSize, rect.size));

        // Factor in the size of the section
        rect = [tableView rectForSection:section];
        tableViewSize = CGSizeMake(CGSizesMaxWidth(tableViewSize, rect.size), CGSizesAddHeights(tableViewSize, rect.size));

        // Factor in the size of the footer
        rect = [tableView rectForFooterInSection:section];
        tableViewSize = CGSizeMake(CGSizesMaxWidth(tableViewSize, rect.size), CGSizesAddHeights(tableViewSize, rect.size));
    }
    return tableViewSize;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For table views whose heights are dynamically sized by their cells' contents--

My `tableView` is contained in a `UIView`, whose `updateConstraints()` function looks like this:

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.tableViewHeight.constant = min(300, self.tableView.contentSize.height)
    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

`tableViewHeight` is an `IBOutlet` to the XIB-assigned height of the table view. I get whichever is smaller--300 points, or the height of the table view's content size.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how much people will like this answer because I am not sure that I like it. But I managed to get something working with this.

This will work for dynamic height cells. The callback will get called a few times as the tableview figures out its contentView

```
class ContentSizeNotifyingTableView: UITableView {
    var contentSizeDidChange: ((CGSize) -> ())?

    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
          self.contentSizeDidChange?(self.contentSize)
        }
    }
}
```