# Swift height of content of table view

Tags: swift, uitableview, height, constraints

Is there a way to find out the height of the content of a table view, beside adding up the height of all cells from all sections?

I have 3 sections each with different height cells and variable number of cells.
So I am hoping for a system method to get the height of the content of the table view.

EDIT: nowhere in the answer of the other similar question does it say where to call the tableView.contentSize

Comment: `contentSize` property does the trick for you. Next time try to look for the answer before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860231/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-uitableviews-content-view

Comment: thank you. I tried, but all I was getting was autoresizing cells and dynamic height of cells instead of the actual table view.

Comment: I added this answer on the other identical question https://stackoverflow.com/a/48566448/1720581

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can retreive the content size by :

**Swift / ObjC :**

```
let contentSize : CGSize = self.tableView.contentSize
let width = self.tableView.contentSize.width
let height = self.tableView.contentSize.height
```

You can use this to know if your `UITableView` is loaded (Swift 2.2):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == (tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!.last! as! NSIndexPath).row {
        // End of loading
        let contentSize : CGSize = self.tableView.contentSize
        let width = self.tableView.contentSize.width
        let height = self.tableView.contentSize.height
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I call this to make sure the table is loaded?
I tried in view did load and it says height is 0.

Comment: Don't forget to +1 if you can :)

Answer (score 2):

Use tableview's content size property to get the height of content in it:

```
tableView.layoutIfNeeded
let tblSize = tbl_Data.contentSize
print(tbl_Data.contentSize.height)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4,5**

1.Set tableview height outlet

[image]

2.Now add IBOutlet of height Constraint like below code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableviewHeightConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

3.Now reload tableview code in viewWillAppear method.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
```

4.Now using get the tableview content size and set into willDisplayCell as tableview height.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

     //Content wise tableview height
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableviewHeightConstraints.constant = tblData.contentSize.height
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Set tableview height outlet.
2. Now using get the tableview content size and set into
   willDisplayCell as tableview height.
3. Don't forget if label data is more then 1 line then set lable line
   is 0.

   override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           //Reload Tableview
           tblData.reloadData()
       }

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell
       return cell
   }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }

    //Content wise tableview height
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        constTblDataHeight.constant = tblData.contentSize
   }
   ```